# algorithm to get events from a time interval

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have a few time intervals with events associated with each interval. I've stored them in a hash map.

```
(0-1]: [a, b, c, d] # time interval from 0 - 1 have events [a, b, c, d]
(1-2]: [a, b] # time interval from 1 - 2 have events [a, b]
(2-3]: [b, c] # time interval from 2- 3 have events [b, c]
```

If my input is 1.5, I know it's between 1 and 2, so I can grab the `1-2` bucket in O(1). Is there another method of storing this data? This is inefficient since I could potentially repeat a lot of events per bucket. My intuition says that this can be stored in a some sort of tree, perhaps a prefix tree? But I can't wrap my mind around it. However, all the tree algorithms have O(logn) lookups, so I guess they won't be as efficient at querying?

Comment: so what do you expect to get for input `time=1.5`? you can't get an event with `time=1.5` from `1-2` bucket, because you don't know which events correspond to exactly `time=1.5`. you should use `key=time`, instead of `key=interval`

Comment: regarding repetitive values, if you use intervals, you may define non-overlapping intervals as keys, like: `[0, 1)` includes 0, excludes 1, `[1,2)` includes 1 excludes 2, etc.

Comment: @mangusta for `time=1.5` for my purposes it's enough that it's between `1-2`. i'm using non-overlapping intervals as keys. i'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interval tree, which Wikipedia [describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) as "a tree data structure" that "allows one to efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or point" in O(log *n* + *m*) time, where *n* is the number of intervals in the tree and *m* is the number of intervals that the query finds. See there for details about how to implement one.

Note that the "intervals" in the interval tree correspond to what you have described as "events": *a*, *b*, etc. The "time intervals" that you refer to (0–1, etc.) are not needed in the interval-tree approach.

> However, all the tree algorithms have O(logn) lookups, so I guess they won't be as effective at querying?

log *n* is smaller than you seem to think. For example, if *n* ≤ 10<sup>9</sup> (meaning, up to one billion intervals), then log *n* < 30. So for most real-world problems, an O(log *n*) algorithm may be thought of as an O(1) algorithm.

(Also, a nit: when referring to performance, we say "efficient" rather than "effective".)